# researching hopf bifurcation

Tags: dynamical-systems

I have located a critical point which is not asymptotically stable and I have tu study the presence of an Hopf bifurcation in that critical point: this kind of bifurcation can occur in that point? Thanks.

Comment: NARQ. $ $ $ $ $ $

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this will happen in a subcritical Hopf bifurcation.